# No output from php helper code in list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.8, php

i have the following code in a helper file:

```
public  function getAvailableAttributesHelper($_product) {
    $_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

    if ($_product->getTypeId()=='configurable')
    {

        //Get Attributes
        $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product);
        if (count($attributes)) 
        {
            $output .= '<ul>';
            foreach($attributes as $att)
            {
                $pAtt=$_product->getProductAttribute();

                //get the child products
                $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
                $frontValues =array();
                $output .= '<ul>';
                $output .= $pAtt->getFrontendLabel();
                $output .= '<ul>';
                foreach($allProducts as $p){
                //check stock, status, ...
                //do not show unsaleable options
                if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue;
                $out=$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName());
                $frontValues[$out]=$out;
            }
            $output .= '<ul>';
            implode('</li><li>', $frontValues);
            $output .= '</li></ul></li>';}
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';

      } else {
         $output .= '<span>To Bad</span>';
      }
      return $output;
}
```

I have the original code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950764/magento-how-to-show-configurable-product-options-in-product-list-page 
This way i can show the available options of the configurable products on the product list page. This is a great wish for our shop. Only we have bought a theme for our store, and that theme generates the products from a helper .... thats why i now try to get this code working in the helper.

In the `\app\design\frontend\theme\default\template\catalog\list.phtml`
is used `<?php echo Mage::helper('mymodule')->getAvailableAttributesHelper($_product) ?>` but without any output. What am i doing wrong?

I have magento 1.8.1 CE

Comment: what is the name and path of a helper file ?

Comment: `app/code/local/Etheme/mymodule/Helper/data.php`

Comment: see this inchoo link http://inchoo.net/magento/display-multiple-configurable-products-with-options-on-one-page-in-magento/

Comment: But i only want to show the options in the list.phtml The orginal code i had found does that for me, only due to my theme i have to code it in a helper file. The if ($_product->getTypeId()=='configurable') is false, even when it's is a configurable product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have optimized the code.

```
public function getAvailableAttributesHelper($_product){
    $html='';
        if($_product->getTypeId()=='configurable'):
            $AllowAttributes=$_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product);
                 $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
                $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)
                                ->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
                $option=array();
                foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                // only show available option
                if(!$product->isSaleable()) continue;
                            foreach ($AllowAttributes as $attribute) {
                                    $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                                    $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                                        $option[$productAttribute->getAttributeCode()][]=$productAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                            }
                }


                $html='<ul>';
                foreach($option  as $key=>$eachoption){
                        //array_unique($eachoption);
                        $html.='<li>'.$key.'<ul>';  
                        //print_r(array_unique($eachoption));
                            foreach(array_unique($eachoption) as $value){
                                $html=$html.'<li>'.$value.'</li>';

                        }
                        $html.='</ul></li>';
                }
                $html.='</ul>';

        endif;
    return $html;
}
```

### output like this:

[image]

Comment: Amit, this code show all options. How can i olny show the available options? For example, when in your first image only the M, L, and XL are in stock. That only these options are shown and S & XS are hidden

Comment: When i add ` `if($product->isSaleable()) continue;` after `foreach ($allProducts as $product) { ...` it does the opposite ... it shows the sold options ...

Answer (score 2):

You should set some breakpoints in your code to see on which `if()`-condition it breaks. My guess would be, that `$attributes` doesn't return a result because your configurable attributes are set to "Show in category listing" -> "No" in the backend unter "Catalog -> Manage Attributes"

== EDIT ==

There are some issues in this code. When you call `$pAtt->getFrontendLabel()`, you don't do anything with it. You should have `$html .= $pAtt->getFrontendLabel();`

Second, you don't return anything from your function. Add `return $html;` in the last line, or the HTML code will not "get back" to your template.

Comment: When I put The original code in The 'list.phtml' then it shows The output. Only I need The helper file to place it At The wanted position

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I edited the code. And put an `else` to the code to see if it works. I do get an output now ... but only  `To Bad`

Comment: So the first if() condition is never true. I formatted your code. See the first line, where you load $_product. Delete it. You should at least read the code you copy -.- Also, you should program in developer-mode (see index.php: Mage::setDeveloperMode(true), which would imeediately have given you an "undefined variable" error due to $product_id in this line.

Comment: The original code, found herte on stackexchange does work on my list.phtml. But due to the design templete i have to put this in the helper file.

Comment: Yes I understood that :) and it is better placed there. And you made some necessary modifications to the code, but not all of them I fear. And the first line re-defines $_product, which overwrites the value you pass to the function. Does it work if you remove this line?

Comment: I works a bit ... but now i get a fatal error on this line: `$output .= $pAtt->getFrontendLabel();` `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getFrontendLabel() on a non-object`

Comment: I hope you could help me a bit ... i am not a programmer in php ... but learning editing them

Comment: You should check why $pAtt = ... A few lines above that error does not return a product attribute. You can use var_dump() to check what it does return. I am on mobile atm and can not test so much. Maybe you can find a hint on this in the original code, and compare what you have changed.

Comment: That did the trick. the var_dump($pAtt) returned `NULL`. So i checked the original code and replaced `$pAtt=$_product->getProductAttribute();` with `$pAtt=$att->getProductAttribute();'